# Creating a room with Three.js and cannon.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, cannon.js

I'm just getting started with Three.js and cannon.js and I've been trying to create a simple room for a while with no success. I'm working off of [this example](http://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/examples/threejs_fps.html) and I've been trying to add walls and a ceiling. What is the easiest way to do this? Right now I have

```
                // wall?
            wallGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 300, 300 );
            wallGeometry.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationX( Math.PI));
            wallMesh = new THREE.Mesh( wallGeometry, material );
            wallMesh.castShadow = false;
            wallMesh.receiveShadow = true;
            scene.add(wallMesh);
```

But it's light up weird and I don't bump into it.... And if I try to add it through cannon.js I get an invisible wall but can't see it. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

THREE.js itself has no physics included so when you create any object in it, it will never make you 'bump' into them by itself. You have to code such features yourself or use another library for that (as you are already trying to do with cannon.js).

Next - per default, THREE js will only create one ambient light for your scene. If you want dynamic lightning and shadows, all lights must be provided by you and objects you want to react to lights must be using MeshLambertMaterial or MeshPhongMaterial, for shadows you will have to set couple of properies and use specific types of lights.

In your example, you don't seem to define wall material anywhere - this might be why walls are invisible.

check these and steal pieces of code you need (and it seems like you will need a lot :-)

http://threejs.org/examples/

http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/index.html